# How do I resend a sampler upon a failed assertion on JMeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am designing a load test in JMeter.
With the current application that we have whenever a HTTP request is sent, the web server will very occasionally send back a page with a message. To get around this we just have to reload the page. This page could come up for literally any HTTP request.

Is there any way to design a test in JMeter where when a sampler fails, the sampler simply retries?
I'm not sure how I can get a Beanshell sampler to resend a HTTP request.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible via additional [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion)

You can re-run arbitrary sampler from the Beanshell Assertion as simple as

```
ctx.getCurrentSampler().sample(null);
```

Add a Beanshell Assertion **after** all other assertions. It matters as assertions are being executed upside-down.

Put the following code into Beanshell Assertion's "Script" area (just change `"message"` to what your server returns on error.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

if (new String(ResponseData).equals("message")) {
    SampleResult result = ctx.getCurrentSampler().sample(null);
    if (result.getResponseDataAsString().equals("message")) {
        Failure = true;
    } else {
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
    }

}
```

You'll have only one result recorded.

- If assertion passes 1st time - it'll be successful
- If assertion fails 1st time and passes 2nd time - it'll be successful
- If assertion fails 2 times - it'll be recorded as failed.

For extended information on Beanshell scripting check out [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Answer (score 1):

Create such hierarchy:

```
   Thread Group (1 user, 1 second ramp-up, forever)
    -While Controller (empty condition = forever)
    --Counter (start – 1, increment  – 1, reference name – counter)
    --HTTP request
    ---Timer (I prefer constant Timer, responseble for pause betwee retrying)
    ---BeanShell Post Processor
```

BeanShell Post Processor should contains(pseudo code):

```
if(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter")>5)
{
  prev.setSuccessful(false);
  prev.setStopTestNow(true);
}
if(successCondition)
{
  prev.setStopTest(true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct way to achieve it, but I think you can use While controller in conjuction with Regex extractor to resend the failed requests.

Logical flow could be,

```
1. HTTP request
2. Regex extractor post processor - check response contains failure extract value in msg variable, default is success    

3. While controller - run till msg=failure, default value of msg is success
```

Example screenshot,

[image]

Let me know if this works.